# How to find the nearest larger element to another element in an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am doing a little preparation for a course I want to take. One of the questions they give as practice is the following:

Write a function, `nearest_larger(arr, i)` which takes an array and an
index. The function should return another index, `j`: this should
satisfy:

(a) `arr[i] < arr[j]`, AND
(b) there is no `j2` closer to `i` than `j` where `arr[i] < arr[j]`.

In case of ties (see example below), choose the earliest (left-most)
of the two indices. If no number in `arr` is larger than `arr[i]`,
return `nil`.

So the code I wrote was:

```
def function(arr,i)
    k = arr.length
    puts "nil" if arr.all? {|number| arr[i] >= number}
        (0..(arr.length-1)).to_a.each do |j|
            if arr[j] > arr[i]
                k = j if((i-j).abs < k) ##
            end
        end
    puts k
end
```

This `function([1,2,6,5,10],3)` returns 4 when it should be return 2.

I am having trouble addressing the scenario when there is a tie. I thought I designed my code to do this(I put ## where I think this is addressed.) Because it should be assigning the index to k if the distance is strictly less than so I don't know why it would return the right side. I hope that makes sense. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You probably want to read up on the [`index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-index) method which, if given a block, does most of what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your current code:

```
def function(arr,i)
    k = i - arr.length # the first result of (i-k).abs should be array length.
    # returns -1 for testability purposes for `puts`
    # this should be changed to return `nil`
    return -1 if arr.all? {|number| arr[i] >= number}
    (0...arr.length).to_a.each do |j|
        if arr[j] > arr[i]
          # since k is an index you should compare distance between i and j
          # against the distance between i and k
          k = j if((i-j).abs < (i-k).abs)
        end
    end
    k
end

puts function([1,2,6,5,10], 0)
puts function([1,2,6,5,10], 1)
puts function([1,2,6,5,10], 2)
puts function([1,2,6,5,10], 3)
puts function([1,2,6,5,10], 4)
```

Output:

```
1
2
4
2
-1
```

Comment: it think `function([1,2,6,5,10], 3)` fails here too

Comment: @kriskova it returns `2`. It doesn't fail.

Comment: it should return 4, no? Nice exercise btw :D

Comment: @kriskova OP's problem is that its current code returns `4` and it should return `2`. The problem states: *In case of ties (see example below), choose the earliest (left-most) of the two indices.*

Comment: Yeah this does it except the instructions ask for "nil" and not -1, which is a very easy fix. The overall idea is perfect and you adapted to my code so I am going to accept. Thanks Luiggi!

Comment: @theamateurdataanalyst yes, I returned -1 for testability purposes. Added that comment as well.

Comment: Wait Luggi one last question. If the second line condition is met how can we adjust the code so it breaks the method?

Comment: @theamateurdataanalyst that cannot be done with your current algorithm. That may be done if you seek on left and right and then compare the results of the distances of both indexes.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza You are right..I did missunderstand that part..my bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
k = arr.length
```

You have defaulted `k` to the length of the array but that's your return value. Best to make it something like `nil` so it doesn't confuse matters.  I think that's where your return value `4` is coming from. If you add a new value onto the array it will the print 5, the new length of the array.

```
puts "nil" if arr.all? {|number| arr[i] >= number}
```

When you do the 'is there any value greater than my index value' test with `all?`, your not returning so the method would continue on and also print the length of the array (see above).

```
(0..(arr.length-1)).to_a.each do |j|
```

[Enumerable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html) (hence [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html)) has an [`each_with_index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) method so you don't need to specify/calculate the index's out the front of loops. You don't need to convert a range `(0..x)` `to_a` to loop around it either.

```
k = j if((i-j).abs < k) ##
```

You're comparing the distance of j to k itself, rather than to the distance of k.

You could cover both tests in a single loop of the array. With the `<` test, the left most answer in a tie takes cares of itself by the order you go over the array.

```
def find_closest_larger_index values, test_index, found = nil

  values.each_with_index do |value,j|
    found = j if value > values[test_index] and ( found.nil? or (test_index - j).abs < (test_index - found).abs  )
  end

  found
end
```

Gives you

```
> find_closest_larger_index [1,2,6,5,10], 0
=> 1
> find_closest_larger_index [1,2,6,5,10], 1
=> 2
> find_closest_larger_index [1,2,6,5,10], 2
=> 4
> find_closest_larger_index [1,2,6,5,10], 3
=> 2
> find_closest_larger_index [1,2,6,5,10], 4
=> nil
```

Comment: I read it as finding the closest larger value... which would be 2 at index 1 ??

Comment: and `find_closest_larger [1,2,6,5,10],1 should return `2`, not `3`

Comment: it should return the closest largers's index

Comment: As in closest in array layout as opposed to value? as long as it is greater in value

Comment: no actually mtm is right. it should be returning the closest thats larger.

Comment: @theamateurdataanalyst then this still won't do because it fails in `find_closest_larger [1,2,6,5,10],1`

Comment: mtm when I write  if arr[j] > arr[i] k = j if((i-j).abs < k) what I was trying to say is if the number is bigger assign to k the j that has the small distance. Is this wrong?

Comment: I'm returning closest by value, not closest by index. 2 secs, now i see why you were comparing indexes =)